# Suggestions for journaling, bullet notes, activity, wiki like application

Tags: note-taking, time-management, wiki, todo, journal

I am looking for an application for Windows that combines some of my favorite features of different applications;  combining a task activity journal / notes, time-tracking, todo lists, a Wiki, and Dashboard.

- Ideally, I would make entries throughout the day, capturing what I did, outcomes, notes, reminders, links (web & files / directories), pictures (easy cut & paste). The notes should allow rich format with bullets, lists (and sub lists), pictures, web links, and file links. Cut paste WYSIWG - AKA word processor.
- The entries would track time (start, end, duration), and have tags.
- Entries can have bullet journal list items with status symbols like [ ] todo, [/] started, [X] done, [-] aborted
- Entries can be organized by relationships and linked like a Wiki with pages and links, and multiple Entries on a page. Preferably allow file links (I get security issues but sure would be nice to reference a directory or a pdf document on my network).
- Entries can have tags and be searched (preferably have a list of existing tags to avoid duplication)
- I can view what I did on a given day, like a journal
- I can track time spent on a day or by tags / projects, similar to Grindstone. Way to visualize data and track total time spent (Burn up/down chart, Dashboard?)
- I can view information like a wiki (if I organize and connect relationships)
- I can pull a list of all bullet journal items based on status and tags, and jump to the entry
- I can search
- Way to export data
- Preferably not store my data in the cloud on someone else's server

Perhaps a tall order, but it feels like there should be something that will do much of this.
I have looked at and used different tools, but they all missed some features. It feels like I want each of the tools but working off a common set of entries, each giving me different views into the data.

1. Word Processor: + nice format, links, etc / - but good no way to search, time track , tag, combine, or track / extract info
2. Spreadsheet: + tracking time / - terrible for text and images, no way to organize / connect information
3. Wiki (Docuwiki): + organizing and connecting information, searchable / - bad for journaling, time tracking
4. Grindstone (I think, have not used it): + tracking tasks / - formatting, links, notes
5. Bullet journal tools (I think): + todo lists with status
6. Kanban board / dashboard: +visualize status and todo lists

Comment: Which OS do you have in mind?

Comment: Oh - yes should have mentioned OS. Windows. I'll update question.

Comment: So this is to help me get organized and save time - and now I am thinking about spending time developing the app my self if only I had some app to organize work ;-).
Only thing that gives me pause is how to integrate "entries" with a wiki. This could be a fun mini-project though, while stuck at home during Corona.

Answer (score 0):

So I am thinking of a possible answer to my own question:

**Build my own journal note entry app linked to a wiki.**

[Zim Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zim_(software)) uses a file based system for wiki. Maybe I could write app to export/sync entries in its files.

Or [WikkaWikki](https://wikkawiki.org/HomePage) uses a MySQL (which is probably what I'd use for journal entries anyway) so perhaps use same DB for Wiki and journal, with Journal app "doing right thing" to enter/sync Entries in wiki.

Does this seem like a good approach?

Or maybe I can customize a wiki with existing plugins - "All" I really need is good journaling / date feature, time tracking, checklist, and tags. Perhaps there already are plugins for this?

Please comment if you have feedback on this idea.

Comment: Zim Wiki will do most of what you're looking for.  Notable execeptions are time tracking and export.  For time tracking, you can insert the date/time in a page with a shortcut key, but there's no mechanism for computing task durations.  Export is pretty limited to HTML, though the files themselves are text, so they can be processed with external programs, and the Tools menu allows those programs to be invoked from within Zim.

Comment: @rd_nielsrn: Interesting. I wonder if I can glue Grindstone and Zim together with some file scanning import export script. I don't really need it real-time. Perhaps some decorated name for grindstone entry and run to sync my "entry" between Zim and grindstone....

Comment: I'm not familiar with Grindstone's capabilities, but if you used a consistent format for entering time notes in a Zim page--e.g., Ctrl-D to insert a timestamp, followed by a note, then you could write and plug in a tool that parses those out of the page's text, computes durations, and adds that information back to the page itself.  Or maybe saves it in some other form, maybe for import to Grindstone if that's possible.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking something like that. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Dendron](https://wiki.dendron.so/). Is it a plugin to vscode, so you have all of vscode's editing and preview features available. There are several good introduction videos available.

While probably not a match for all the points you mention, it has for instance bullet point support and also specific support for date specific journal entries. It is using git as backing storage, so you have full control of where you host the content.